# How can I work with absolute layout in javafx?

Tags: java, swing, layout, javafx, absolute

I'm new in javafx 
and I want to start building a project 
but the problem is I don't know how to use absolute layout in javafx
In swing i just write :

```
setLayout(null);
JButton b = new JButton("Here is a test");
b.setBounds(20, 10, width, hieght); // here is how i use the absolute layout in swing
```

But in javafx the things are more complex

Therefore I really need help.
I've already seen all the javafx layouts here:

[Using Built-in Layout Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm)

But nothing could help me.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

In JavaFX, there is no separate `LayoutManager` class. There is a set of predefined layout panes, subclassing `Pane`, which lay the child nodes out in different ways.

The [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) class does no layout, so using it is the closest equivalent to using a `null` layout manager in Swing. Incidentally, this approach is not really recommended, either in Swing or in JavaFX.

The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) runs through the built-in layout panes. There is also a useful [presentation](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/interface-layout-javafx-2-0) (requires registration to Parleys) on general layout in JavaFX 2 and later.

Comment: thnx bro :) you really help

Comment: @ayoubsoso if this helped you, you should rather accept the answer & upvote